# Regular express to find all lower case string with dot with Python

Tags: python, regex

Trying with python to find all strings inside a double quote, and with domain name like format, such as `"abc.def.ghi"`.

I am currently using `re.findall('\"([a-z\\.]+[a-z]*)\"', input_string)`,

`[a-z\\.]+` is for `abc.`, `def.` and `[a-z]*` is for `ghi`.

So far it has no issue to match all string like `"abc.def.ghi"`, but it also matches string that contains no `.`, such as `"opq"`, `"rst"`.

Question is, how to get rid of those string contains no dot `.` using regx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pattern**

```
'"([a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+)"'
```

**Explanation**

- Start & end with a double quote
- capture group

  - [a-z]+        one letter a-z
  - (?:...)       nested non-capturomg subgroup of the capture group

    - period followed by at least one letter a-z (repeated at least once)
    - the nested subgroup is repeated at least once
    - make subgroup non-capturing since otherwise findall will only report this subgroup

**Usage**

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\"[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+\"')
tests = ['"abc.def.ghi"', '"opq"']
for input_string in tests:
    print(f"input_string: {input_string}, findall:  {pattern.findall(input_string)}")
```

**Output**

```
input_string: "abc.def.ghi", found:  ['abc.def.ghi']
input_string: "opq", found:  []
```

Comment: This is working. Thanks. Learnt from it.

Comment: You  don't have to escape the `\"`

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-z\\.]+
```

this part. matches any character a-z or .
if you want the dot to be there, you will have to move it outside the character set
something like

```
([a-z]+\\.)+
```

result:
[visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av2CO.png)

Comment: tested with `re.findall('\"(([a-z]+\\.)+[a-z]*)\"', input_string)`, it captures `abc.def.ghi` and `def.`. Because `()` is used for capturing.